# Difference between “Auffassen” and “Begreifen” in Hegel's “Phänomenologie des Geistes”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Here's the first paragraph from Hegel’s *Phänomenologie des Geistes:*

> Das Wissen, welches zuerst oder unmittelbar unser Gegenstand ist, kann kein anderes sein als dasjenige, welches selbst unmittelbares Wissen, Wissen des Unmittelbaren oder Seienden ist. Wir haben uns ebenso unmittelbar oder aufnehmend zu verhalten, also nichts an ihm, wie es sich darbietet, zu verändern und von dem Auffassen das Begreifen abzuhalten.

In other words, he's saying that in his investigation he will try to analyze things exactly as they appear to him, to be as faithful as he can to his direct experience.

What is not clear to me the separation he tries to do between *Auffassen* and *Begreifen*. From what I've looked up, the two verbs are very similar, roughly meaning *understand,* so it looks like he's playing with some subtle difference.

In an English edition I've found, the translator makes the distinction *apprehending* vs. *comprehending.*

If this is correct, which one is *auffassen* and which is *begreifen*?

Is this distinction common in German or is it just a technical thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Auffassen* und *Begreifen* sind im normalen Sprachgebrauch Synonyme. Beide beschreiben ursprünglich faktische Tätigkeiten, die man mit den Händen ausführt ("fassen" und "greifen"), die metaphorisch in die "Denkwelt" übernommen wurden und mit *manuellen* Tätigkeiten nichts mehr zu tun haben.

Hegel unterscheidet in seiner Begriffswelt das *Auffassen* vom *Begreifen*, indem er ihm eine sammelnde (und in gewisser Weise auch eine subjektive) Komponente zuschreibt, während der *Begriff* die komplette abstrakte Wesenheit eines Dings und seine Beziehungen zu anderen Dingen umfasst. Es handelt sich also um eine fachliche Begrifflichkeit, die Hegel den eigentlichen Synonymen aufprägt.

Comment: +1. Meinst Du im 1. Satz eigentlich "fassen und *greifen"?

Comment: @marquinho ja, natürlich - danke!

Answer (score 4):

I am not an expert on Hegel. That said, this is my take on it:

The differentiation between *apprehend* and *comprehend* is a very good translation. *apprehend* is the translation of *auffassen*, and *comprehend* is the translation of *begreifen*.

Hegel wants to define a certain kind of knowledge which is "unmediated" - *unmittelbar*. Usually, the word *unmittelbar* rather means *immediate*, but Hegel uses it in a literal way here. Today, we would probably say *unvermittelt*.  He wants to express that there is no medium between the knowledge and "us", that the knowledge comes to us directly. The potential medium Hegel is having in mind here, is reason.

You are right, there is no big difference in normal language between *auffassen* and *begreifen*. Hegel uses the words in a slightly idiosyncratic way, giving them a difference in meaning they don't have in non-Hegel German. *begreifen* is the verb to the noun *Begriff* ("notion"). And *Begriff* is a high-order concept, the result of a cognitive process. So, that is why I think that *begreifen* is very well translated as *comprehend*.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my two cents to the already-existing answers, I think a (simplified) comparison "German - French - English" could be insightful here:

- "fassen" (German) = "prendre" (French) = to take (English)
- "auf-fassen" (German) = "com-prendre" (French) = to... "with-take"?? (English)

Therefore, I think the English translation of "to comprehend" looks rather appropriate ?!

Please feel free to correct me as I am not a German speaker.